# Drizzle and mapDispatchToProps not working

Tags: truffle, react, drizzle

I'm still struggling with Drizzle, trying to dispatch my own action. Based on the Drizzle box, I added the following to HomeContainer:

```
import Home from './Home';
import {drizzleConnect} from 'drizzle-react';
import * as actions from '../../store/actions/actions';

// May still need this even with data function to refresh component on updates for this contract.
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        accounts: state.accounts,
        SimpleStorage: state.contracts.SimpleStorage,
        TutorialToken: state.contracts.TutorialToken,
        Series: state.contracts.Series,
        drizzleStatus: state.drizzleStatus,
        rates: state.rates.ethRate
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onGetEthRate: (fiatSymbol) => {console.log(dispatch); dispatch(actions.getEthRate(fiatSymbol));}
    };
};

const HomeContainer = drizzleConnect(Home, mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);

export default HomeContainer;
```

The getEthRate action creator looks like this:

```
export const getEthRate = (fiatSymbol) => {
    console.log("Getting ETH rate for " + fiatSymbol);
    return {
        type: actionTypes.GET_ETH_RATE,
        fiatSymbol: fiatSymbol
    };
};
```

And then I registered a saga to process that action in rootSaga.js:

```
export default function* root() {
    yield all(
        drizzleSagas.map(saga => fork(saga)),
        takeEvery(actionTypes.GET_ETH_RATE, getEthRateSaga)
    );
}
```

But the following saga is never triggered, as I never see the log in the console:

```
export function* getEthRateSaga(action) {
    console.log("Fetching ETH rate for " + action.fiatSymbol);
    try {
        const response = yield http.get('/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=' + action.fiatSymbol);
        const rate = response.data[action.fiatSymbol];
        yield put(actions.updateEthRate(action.fiatSymbol, rate));
    } catch(error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

And based on the Redux dev console, the GET_ETH_RATE action is not even dispatched, so I'm wondering if mapDispatchToProps works with drizzleConnect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so I figured it out. I was misled by Redux DevTools that made me think that the action was not dispatched because when I filtered on the action's name, I didn't see anything. But apparently, the action was dispatched, but not picked up by Saga because there was a mistake in my initialization there:

```
export default function* root() {
    yield all(
        drizzleSagas.map(saga => fork(saga)),
        takeEvery(actionTypes.GET_ETH_RATE, getEthRateSaga)
    );
}
```

The issue is that all() expects an array, and I pass it an array and an isolated object. Here is the right syntax to fix that and append my takeEvery to the result of drizzleSagas.map():

```
export default function* root() {
    yield all([
        ...drizzleSagas.map(saga => fork(saga)),
        takeEvery(actionTypes.GET_ETH_RATE, getEthRateSaga)
    ]);
}
```

With that, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your connect implementation is fine. Drizzle accepts mapDispatchToProps as you've implemented it here. (See the [source here](https://github.com/trufflesuite/drizzle-react/blob/master/src/drizzleConnect.js), if interested.) It looks to me like you've got a simple import error. You're exporting the action creator directly (`export const getEthRate`), but referencing it as `actions.getEthRate`. That would match up with the behavior you are seeing where the action is never dispatched, since `actions.getEthRate` would be undefined.

Comment: I added the full content of HomeContainer for reference, and as you can see, I am importing actions.